Exo Player: HLS is not Playing
Here is my HLS URL: https://30a-tv.com/feeds/mwaretv/30atv.m3u8.
Above HLS URL, I have tested in online stream tester but am unable to play.
Error Code: 50001
But above HLS video URL playing is expected in other players like Roku video Player, AVplayer, and Video JS Player.

well, you should probably fix your code and it will start working (answer as much detailed as question, ALWAYS post some sample code and put more technical destription)
